# Switch by class (instanceof) in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, instanceof

It is possible to replace block of `if( .. instanceof ...), elseif(... instanceof ...), ...`  with switch?

For example:

```
<?php
$class = ..... //some class

if($class instanceof SomeClass) {
    //do something
} elseif($class instanceof SomeAnotherClass) {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For a polymorphic switch with `instanceof` which considers inheritance:

```
switch(true) {  
    case $objectToTest instanceof TreeRequest:
        echo "tree request";
        break;
    case $objectToTest instanceof GroundRequest:
        echo "ground request";
        break;
}
```

For a switch where the class name should match exactly:

```
$class = get_class($objectToTest);

switch($class) {  
    case 'TreeRequest':
        echo "tree request";
        break;
    case 'GroundRequest':
        echo "ground request";
        break;
}
```

Comment: that switch(true), :+1:

Comment: A warning to anyone looking at using the first example: it's not the same as `instanceof` as it ignores class inheritance and implementations.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But **why oh why** would you want to do that in the first place? There's nothing wrong with `if( .. instanceof ...), elseif(... instanceof ...)`. Not only the first example is incorrect, but the second one takes also much more space, degrades readability and efficiency (as it prevents compiling the "cases" statements as they are dynamic.
Don't do such thing.

Comment: Beware, the danger of using `get_class($object)` is that some frameworks (like Symfony) return the **Proxy** classname (like when lazy loading,...), so not the real classnames you want to compare with!

Answer (score 46):

The following is more correct:

```
$class = get_class($objectToTest);

switch($class) {  
    case TreeRequest::class:
        echo "tree request";
        break;
    case GroundRequest::class:
        echo "ground request";
        break;
}
```

This way namespaces are properly compared (you don't have to type them out) and if anything changes such as the namespace or class name you'll get a decent IDE error informing you that your code is broken.

Comment: remember that this way you miss subclasses (class inheritance and implementations)

Comment: to ensure this solution works even when `$objectToTest` is a proxy, you can use `$class = ClassUtils::getClass($objectToTest);`

Comment: @Roubi exactly what I was looking for (Symfony/Doctrine)

Answer (score 16):

And using the `match` expression this would look like this:

```
return match(get_class($object)) {  
   TreeRequest::class => "tree request",
   GroundRequest::class => "ground request",
   default => "default request"
};
```

Remember it misses inheritance and takes only the current class. Match expression considering inheritance:

```
return match(true) {  
   $object instanceof TreeRequest=> "tree request",
   $object instanceof GroundRequest => "ground request",
   default => "default request"
};
```

Comment: `Match expressions are available as of PHP 8.0.0.`

Comment: default  ***must*** be present if it can happen that there is no `true` case!